# when and where is first occurence of word "zap"?

Tags: neologisms, technology

when and where is first occurence of word "zap" ?
Online Etymology dictionnary mentions comic strip Buck Rogers but without any precise date or quotation

Comment: "Zap" was used as a character name by Samuel Taylor Coleridge back in the early 1800s.  No telling where that came from.  But I've always assumed that the sci-fi term came from the sound of an electric spark.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term earliest appearance appears to be from 1929 as a noun. The comic strips “[Buck Rogers in the Twenty-Fifth Century](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Buck_Rogers_comic_strips)" were published from 1929 to 1967 and, apparently, used the term quite often.

***[Zap:](https://greensdictofslang.com/search/basic?q=zap) (noun)***

> (orig. US) an excl. used to describe the force of a sudden impact:

> ***1929***        P.F. Nowlan in Wash. Post 7 May 16/3: *Ahead of me was one of those golden dragon Mongols, with a deadly disintegrator ray... Br-r-rr-r-z-zzz-zap.*

***Zap: (verb)***

> (orig. US milit.) to kill, to defeat.

> ***1942***    [US]    Berrey & Van den Bark - The American Thesaurus of  SlAng.

(GDoS)

Here is a strip from 1933 where the term zap as a verb is used:

[image]

From ([rolandanderson.se](http://rolandanderson.se/comics/buckrogers/buckrogers.php))

Comment: thank you very much